# How can I disable the Toshiba Bluetooth Stack Popup when I connect my headset?

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, toshiba-stack

I have a USB Bluetooth radio to connect my jawbone headset to my computer. I'm currently using the Toshiba Stack on Windows 8 Professional and it works fine, however I want to disable the popups that appear every time I connect my headset.

The popup states that the device is not the default communication device. Even if it **is** the default communication device, it still does this.

It's frustrating because it will minimize the game I'm playing when I connect the headset.

Does anyone know how to stop these popups from appearing automatically every time? Or can someone recommend a bluetooth dongle that works well with headsets?

Otherwise, is there a better Bluetooth Stack for Windows that automatically connects headsets when they are turned on? The Windows Bluetooth stack is out of the question--it's garbage. I've also tried WIDCOMM and I always get loud popping sounds in my mic that my friends can hear during chat.

---

Note: **I'm not referring to a notification tray balloon.** The software actually loads up the Window's Audio Settings control panel, because it thinks you want to set your headset to the default playback device. I do not want to do that because I have the sound come out of my speakers and mumble come out of the headset.

I've googled a lot and haven't found anything. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable all Windows Notification Ballons if you wish:

> Open up regedit.exe through the start menu search or run box, and then
>   browse down to the following key:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> Right-click on the right-hand pane, and create a new 32-bit DWORD with
>   the following values:
>
> ```
> Name: EnableBalloonTips
> Value: 0
> ```
>
> You’ll have to logoff and back on in order to see the change… or to be
>   more correct, you won’t see any popup balloons anymore.
>
> Source: [How-to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-all-notification-balloons-in-windows-vista/)

Actually, you need not do a registry hack. It's as simple as right-clicking the system tray and disabling all notifications from the programs on the system tray.