# Toshiba Bluetooth Stack Pops up Windows Audio Settings Whenever Connecting a Headset

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable the Toshiba Bluetooth Stack Popup when I connect my headset?](https://superuser.com/questions/528313/how-can-i-disable-the-toshiba-bluetooth-stack-popup-when-i-connect-my-headset)

I have a USB Bluetooth radio to connect my jawbone headset to my computer. I'm currently using the Toshiba Stack on Windows 8 Professional and it works fine. I want to disable it loading the Windows Audio Settings control panel item that appears every time I connect my headset. It states that the device is not the default communication device, and thinks that it's doing me a favor by opening up the audio control panel. Even if it is the default communication device, it still does this.

It's frustrating because it will minimize the game I'm playing when I connect the headset.

Any help would be appreciated. Otherwise, is there a better bluetooth stack for Windows that automatically connects headsets when they are turned on? The Windows bluetooth stack is out of the question--it's garbage. I've also tried WIDCOMM and I always get loud popping sounds in my mic that my friends can hear during chat.

Does anyone know how to stop these popups from appearing automatically every time? Or can someone recommend a bluetooth dongle that works well with headsets?

I have searched google but havent had any luck, So I would definitely appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should make an account so I can downvote the answer. Also, I was concerned it wouldn't get anymore attention since 2 people already downvoted my question.

Comment: Someone else down-voting doesn't deter me from checking a question out myself, but perhaps others think differently. Yeah, you should definitely register. Edit: Just remembered though, [you'll need 125 rep here before you can down-vote](http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-down).